# Java Robot click side button

Tags: java, mouseevent

I want to use Robot to click mouse button 4, side button.

The `InputEvent` only have the 3 standard left, middle (scroll) and right buttons.

```
InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK = 1024
InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK = 2048
InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK = 4096
```

So I tried to flow the formula and send to the `Robot` the number `8192`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Robot mouseHandler = new Robot();

        mouseHandler.mousePress(8192);
        mouseHandler.mouseRelease(8192);
    } catch (AWTException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it didn't work (as expected) and throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination of button flags
    at java.awt.Robot.checkButtonsArgument(Robot.java:320)
    at java.awt.Robot.mousePress(Robot.java:256)
    at controller_client.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:30)
```

Is it possible to create a mouse click with button 4?

Comment: I'm thinking that you might have to use JNA or JNI to solve this problem

Comment: I also have to wonder if your issue is not only OS-specific, but also *vendor*-specific, since I don't know if handling of extra and perhaps unusual mouse buttons has been fully addressed by most common OS's.

Comment: I using windows 10 and I am pretty sure that it is addressed because I used `MouseEvent` in `JFrame` to see if it is detects button4 and button5 and it does, it did printed the numbers 4 and 5 when I pressed them.

Comment: OK, then you should be able to call `getModifiersEx()` on the MouseEvent in your MouseListener to get the extended modifier mask for this event. When you do this, what int value is returned?

Comment: WOW Ok, so this is the result: 

`button1 (Left) = 1,024`,
`button2 (Scroll) = 2,048`,
`button3 (Right) = 4,096`,
`button4 (forwards) = 16,384`,
`button5 (backwards) = 32,768`

I did tried it and it works thanks :).
I wanted to check more buttons but I only have those buttons on my mouse. I tried to send the numbers `65,536` and `131,072` but it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` probably because I don't have those buttons on my mouse. If anyone have a mouse with more buttons like `g502` so please comment here if you can detect more button.

Comment: I found this method that return the button mask for any button number `MouseEvent.getMaskForButton(buttonNum)` so this solve my problem

Comment: Great. Thanks for the heads up. Please post an official answer to the question so that future visitors might benefit from your discoveries.

Comment: The answer shouldn't be in the question itself but rather posted as an answer

Comment: I answered but I don't have the best grammar.

Comment: Looks good to me -- 1+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after searching more I found this function that return any mouse button mask from 1 to 20 `MouseEvent.getMaskForButton(int button)`.

After trying it the `Robot` class did manage to click the button4 and button5, side buttons, like so:

```
try
{
    Robot mouseHandler = new Robot();

    int mouseButtonNum = 4; // 1 - 20
                            // but only buttons from 1 to 5 did work with Robot

    mouseHandler.mousePress(MouseEvent.getMaskForButton(mouseButtonNum));
    mouseHandler.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.getMaskForButton(mouseButtonNum));
} catch (AWTException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used a mouse with 3 buttons and `Robot` did manage to click 4 and 5 buttons. But it seems like that `Robot` only can click buttons from 1 to 5, so 
probably [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)'s explanation is correct:

> I also have to wonder if your issue is not only OS-specific, but also vendor-specific, since I don't know if handling of extra and perhaps unusual mouse buttons has been fully addressed by most common OS's.

If he does right then the OS that I use is Windows 10. If someone have `Linux` and he knows how to address more mouse buttons to `Linux` and tried to make `Robot` click mouse button above 5 so please note me if it works or not.