# How to press the side buttons of the mouse with java robot?

Tags: java

Does anybody know what the code for the side buttons of the mouse are?

```
robot.mousePress(???)
robot.mouseRelease(???)
```

There are 3 buttons for the mouse, but what about the side buttons. How can they be pressed?

Comment: @Schred no i did not.

Comment: @DinuNicolae I'm pretty sure the side buttons are basically shortcuts for keyboard keys (or combinatons of the keys).

Comment: Create A Setting application with a `MouseListener` that outputs the code of the button pressed.

Comment: @daniu This makes sense. I will try

Comment: look this question, I hope it solved your problem [Java Robot click side button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436569/java-robot-click-side-button)